# exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, boost, boost-python

I get the error "Exception Specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration" in VS2015 and it seems to be coming from

```
template <typename T, bool isp, bool b1, bool b2>
struct ct_imp
{
   typedef const T& param_type;
};
```

and in other place

```
template <typename T>
struct call_traits
{
public:
   typedef T value_type;
   typedef T& reference;
   typedef const T& const_reference;
   //
   // C++ Builder workaround: we should be able to define a compile time
   // constant and pass that as a single template parameter to ct_imp<T,bool>,
   // however compiler bugs prevent this - instead pass three bool's to
   // ct_imp<T,bool,bool,bool> and add an extra partial specialisation
   // of ct_imp to handle the logic. (JM)
   typedef typename boost::detail::ct_imp<
      T,
      ::boost::is_pointer<T>::value,
      ::boost::is_arithmetic<T>::value,
      ::boost::is_enum<T>::value
   >::param_type param_type;
};
```

in call_traits.hpp file.

The above template is instantiated in one other file "compressed_pair.hpp" and face same error in these places too.

```
class compressed_pair_imp<T1, T2, 2>
      : protected ::boost::remove_cv<T2>::type
   {
   public:
      typedef T1                                                 first_type;
      typedef T2                                                 second_type;
      typedef typename call_traits<first_type>::param_type       first_param_type;
      typedef typename call_traits<second_type>::param_type      second_param_type;
      typedef typename call_traits<first_type>::reference        first_reference;
      typedef typename call_traits<second_type>::reference       second_reference;
      typedef typename call_traits<first_type>::const_reference  first_const_reference;
      typedef typename call_traits<second_type>::const_reference second_const_reference;
```

These are boost files and I've not modified those. While i build my current project in vs2015 with new boost 1.58 libraries, I get this error.

Below is the complete compilation details.

```
     CommandManager_Wrapper.cpp
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(184): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(348): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::details::compressed_pair_imp<T1,T2,2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              T2=boost::python::default_call_policies
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/detail/caller.hpp(251): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::compressed_pair<F,Policies>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              Policies=boost::python::default_call_policies
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/detail/caller.hpp(169): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1>::impl<F,CallPolicies,Sig>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              CallPolicies=boost::python::default_call_policies,
1>              Sig=boost::mpl::vector2<unsigned int,CommandContextList &>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/make_function.hpp(61): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::detail::caller<F,CallPolicies,Sig>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              CallPolicies=boost::python::default_call_policies,
1>              Sig=boost::mpl::vector2<unsigned int,CommandContextList &>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/make_function.hpp(146): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<F,CallPolicies,Signature,boost::mpl::int_<0>>(F,const CallPolicies &,const Sig &,const boost::python::detail::keyword_range &,NumKeywords)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              CallPolicies=boost::python::default_call_policies,
1>              Signature=boost::mpl::vector2<unsigned int,CommandContextList &>,
1>              Sig=boost::mpl::vector2<unsigned int,CommandContextList &>,
1>              NumKeywords=boost::mpl::int_<0>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(545): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::api::object boost::python::make_function<Fn,boost::python::default_call_policies,boost::python::detail::keywords<0>,boost::mpl::vector2<unsigned int,CommandContextList &>>(F,const CallPolicies &,const Keywords &,const Signature &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Fn=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              F=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              CallPolicies=boost::python::default_call_policies,
1>              Keywords=boost::python::detail::keywords<0>,
1>              Signature=boost::mpl::vector2<unsigned int,CommandContextList &>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(615): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::def_impl<CommandContextList,Fn,boost::python::detail::def_helper<A1,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>>(T *,const char *,Fn,const Helper &,...)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Fn=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              A1=char [45],
1>              T=CommandContextList,
1>              Helper=boost::python::detail::def_helper<char [45],boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(615): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::def_impl<CommandContextList,Fn,boost::python::detail::def_helper<A1,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>>(T *,const char *,Fn,const Helper &,...)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Fn=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              A1=char [45],
1>              T=CommandContextList,
1>              Helper=boost::python::detail::def_helper<char [45],boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(245): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::def_maybe_overloads<A1,char[45]>(const char *,Fn,const char (&),...)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              A1=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              Fn=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(245): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::def_maybe_overloads<A1,char[45]>(const char *,Fn,const char (&),...)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              A1=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              Fn=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const
1>          ]
1>  ..\..\..\OsIndependent\Libs\py_sfcl\CommandManager_Wrapper.cpp(155): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified> &boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::def<unsigned int(__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::* )(void) noexcept const,char[45]>(const char *,A1,const A2 (&))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CommandContextPtr,
1>              A1=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              A2=char [45]
1>          ]
1>  ..\..\..\OsIndependent\Libs\py_sfcl\CommandManager_Wrapper.cpp(155): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified> &boost::python::class_<CommandContextList,boost::noncopyable,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::def<unsigned int(__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::* )(void) noexcept const,char[45]>(const char *,A1,const A2 (&))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CommandContextPtr,
1>              A1=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const,
1>              A2=char [45]
1>          ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/call_traits.hpp(77): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(186): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::call_traits<unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::* )(void) noexcept const>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=CommandContextPtr
1>          ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/call_traits.hpp(78): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/call_traits.hpp(79): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/call_traits.hpp(50): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/call_traits.hpp(91): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::ct_imp<T,false,false,false>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=unsigned int (__thiscall std::deque<CommandContextPtr,std::allocator<CommandContextPtr>>::* )(void) noexcept const
1>          ]
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/call_traits.hpp(91): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(186): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(188): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(190): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(358): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(360): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(362): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp(364): error C2279: exception specification cannot appear in a typedef declaration
1>c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp(133): warning C4459: declaration of 'self' hides global declaration
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/self.hpp(24): note: see declaration of 'boost::python::self_ns::self'
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/type_traits/alignment_of.hpp(42): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::objects::value_holder<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=CommandContext_Net
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/type_traits/alignment_of.hpp(65): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::alignment_of_hack<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/type_traits/alignment_of.hpp(89): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::alignment_of_impl<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/instance.hpp(29): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::alignment_of<Data>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Data=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/instance.hpp(44): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::objects::instance<Holder>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Holder=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp(35): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::objects::additional_instance_size<Holder>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Holder=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_wrapper.hpp(29): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'PyObject *boost::python::objects::make_instance_impl<T,Holder,boost::python::objects::make_instance<T,Holder>>::execute<const boost::reference_wrapper<const T>>(Arg &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=CommandContext_Net,
1>              Holder=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>,
1>              Arg=const boost::reference_wrapper<const CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_wrapper.hpp(29): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'PyObject *boost::python::objects::make_instance_impl<T,Holder,boost::python::objects::make_instance<T,Holder>>::execute<const boost::reference_wrapper<const T>>(Arg &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=CommandContext_Net,
1>              Holder=boost::python::objects::value_holder<CommandContext_Net>,
1>              Arg=const boost::reference_wrapper<const CommandContext_Net>
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_wrapper.hpp(28): note: while compiling class template member function 'PyObject *boost::python::objects::class_cref_wrapper<T2,boost::python::objects::make_instance<T2,boost::python::objects::value_holder<T>>>::convert(const Src &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net,
1>              T=CommandContext_Net,
1>              Src=CommandContext_Net
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/converter/as_to_python_function.hpp(27): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'PyObject *boost::python::objects::class_cref_wrapper<T2,boost::python::objects::make_instance<T2,boost::python::objects::value_holder<T>>>::convert(const Src &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net,
1>              T=CommandContext_Net,
1>              Src=CommandContext_Net
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(272): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::objects::class_cref_wrapper<T2,boost::python::objects::make_instance<T2,boost::python::objects::value_holder<T>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net,
1>              T=CommandContext_Net
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(229): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>::maybe_register_class_to_python<T2>(T2 *,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(229): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>::maybe_register_class_to_python<T2>(T2 *,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(219): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>::register_aux2<T,use_callback>(T2 *,Callback)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              T=CommandContext_Net,
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net,
1>              Callback=use_callback
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(219): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>::register_aux2<T,use_callback>(T2 *,Callback)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              T=CommandContext_Net,
1>              T2=CommandContext_Net,
1>              Callback=use_callback
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(217): note: while compiling class template member function 'void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>::register_aux(void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/object/class_metadata.hpp(205): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>::register_aux(void *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(175): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::objects::class_metadata<W,X1,X2,X3>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              W=CommandContext_Net,
1>              X1=boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,
1>              X2=boost::python::detail::not_specified,
1>              X3=boost::python::detail::not_specified
1>          ]
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(636): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::class_<CommandContext_Net,boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::id_vector' being compiled
1>  c:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost/python/class.hpp(636): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::python::class_<CommandContext_Net,boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::class_(const char *,boost::python::no_init_t)'
1>  ..\..\..\OsIndependent\Libs\py_sfcl\CommandManager_Wrapper.cpp(128): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::python::class_<CommandContext_Net,boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>::class_(const char *,boost::python::no_init_t)' being compiled
1>  ..\..\..\OsIndependent\Libs\py_sfcl\CommandManager_Wrapper.cpp(128): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::python::class_<CommandContext_Net,boost::python::bases<CommandContext,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_,boost::mpl::void_>,boost::python::detail::not_specified,boost::python::detail::not_specified>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: Include the code which instantiates the templates.

Comment: I've included the code where it is instantiated and also the compilation log.

Comment: You're compiling under C++14?

Comment: VS2015 with boost_1_58

Comment: As written there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7c38yzs9(v=vs.100).aspx
Either change your compilation settings or do a regex search and replace all these noexcept with nothing.

Comment: It was a problem with size() function in deque. In C++98, its prototype is size_type size() const; and in c++11, its size_type size() const noexcept;
I had used typedef in one of the instantiation that makes use of this Size().  So, replaced my original code &CommandContextList::size with a function pointer by addiing below function size_t get_params_size(CommandContextList const& p)
{
 return p.size();
}

Comment: what about writing all important information in a question: `..\..\..\OsIndependent\Libs\py_sfcl\CommandManager_Wrapper.cpp(155)` & line 128 ------ is it solved?